# Bind eventListener issue

Tags: cocos2d-js

i have a issue with the binding of my events with your respective sprite.

This is my code:

```
var GameLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    sprite:null,
    ctor:function () {
        this._super();
        var size = cc.winSize;

        var gradient = cc.LayerGradient(cc.color(0,0,0,255),cc.color(0x46,0x82,0xB4,255));
        this.addChild(gradient);

        for(i=0;i<16;i++){
            var tile = new MemoryTile();
            this.addChild(tile,0);
            tile.setPosition(49+i%4*74,400-Math.floor(i/4)*74);
        }

        return true;
    }
});


var MemoryTile = cc.Sprite.extend({
    ctor:function() {
        this._super();
        this.initWithFile(res.cover);

        var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
        event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
        swallowTouches: true,
        onTouchBegan: function (touch, event) {
            var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
            var location = target.convertToNodeSpace(touch.getLocation());
            var targetSize = target.getContentSize();
            var targetRectangle = cc.rect(0, 0, targetSize.width, targetSize.height);
                if (cc.rectContainsPoint(targetRectangle, location)) {
                    console.log("I picked a tile!!");
                }
                //console.log('touche po oe: ' + targetSize);    
                return true;
            }
        });

        cc.eventManager.addListener(listener.clone(), this);
    }
});
```

So, the problem is that only the first sprite created still with the eventListener, i think the **listener.clone()** is not working, any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the create method is deprecated, this should work just fine inside memory tile instead of the var listener and the add listener:

```
cc.eventManager.addListener({
            event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
            swallowTouches: false,
            onTouchBegan: function (touch, event) {
                var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
                var location = target.convertToNodeSpace(touch.getLocation());
                var targetSize = target.getContentSize();
                var targetRectangle = cc.rect(0, 0, targetSize.width, targetSize.height);
                if (cc.rectContainsPoint(targetRectangle, location)) {
                    console.log("I picked a tile!!");
                }
                //console.log('touche po oe: ' + targetSize);   
                return true;
            }
        }, this);
```

Comment: It works! The official documentation of cocos2d-js is a crap, thx dude!